# Force "0" if edittext left blank

Tags: java, android

so I have tried some of the methods in prior posts re this problem yet none of them seem to work for me (user error no doubt).

Basically my calculation button will crash if a edittext is left blank. What I need to happen is that if it is left blank, the edittext is given a value of 0.

Here is my java:

```
public class kCals extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText firstNumber;
EditText secondNumber;
EditText thirdNumber;
TextView addResult;
Button btnAdd;
double num1,num2,num3,sum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_k_cals);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    {
    firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
    secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
    thirdNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber3);
    addResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
            num3 = Double.parseDouble(thirdNumber.getText().toString());
            sum = (num1 * 4) + (num2 * 4) + (num3 * 9);
            addResult.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum));}
        });

   }}}
```

If anyone can help with this that would be great.
Cheers, 
Jess.

Comment: Show what you have tried. This one is so basic, it's a good learning experience to show your failures.

Comment: You could check if string inside EditText is null. if not null, parse to double. else, set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to have a method do this for you like the following.

```
public double parseDouble(String doubleText) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(doubleText)) {
        return 0;
    }

    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(doubleText);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // do something if invalid number maybe also return 0?
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
num1 = parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
num2 = parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
num3 = parseDouble(thirdNumber.getText().toString());
```

You could also update the method to pass the `EditText` objects themselves to avoid all the `getText().toString()` calls if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a check before u parse.

```
if(firstNumber.getText().toString() != ""){
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
}
else{
    num1 = 0;
}
```

Note that this will still output exceptions if you allow entries other than numbers in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a function to check for the text. For example :

```
double getValue(Editable text){
   if (text == null || text.length() == 0){
     return 0;
} else {
   return Double.parseDouble(text.toString());
}
}
```

and call it :

```
num1 = getValue(firstNumber.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really basic. Parsing a `String` to a `Double` may occur some unexpected, so the try-catch is the best choice for you to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your edittext value length something like
String s = edittext.gettext().toString();
If(s.length()!=0)
    Your stuff